# How to get list of files which include string with quotes (using grep command)

Tags: string, unix, grep, ksh

I have lost of xmls in Unix env, and I want to get list of the files which include the next string:
Value value="99.00"

My problem is that this string include quotes, which causing me truobles with the grep command. any idea which command I should use?

SHELL=/bin/ksh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use backslash to escape the `"`:

```
grep Value\ value=\"99.00\" *.xml
```

Or enclose it in single quotes:

```
grep 'Value value="99.00"' *.xml
```

Comment: I did as much as I could, you didn't provide us much info.

Comment: well, how you execute grep. My example is for your input string and a file file.txt

Comment: Do you know the syntax of grep? Did you provide the correct file to it or you used the one I shown as an example? You can use e.g. `*.xml` instead of `file.txt`.

Comment: This command worked for me:
grep -l Value\ value=\"99.00\" *.xml